# Looking for study on the pollution of the forest

Tags: pollution, forest

I hope that my question fits in this forum.
I am looking for empirical literature dedicated to pollution in the forest.
So far, I have only found psychological literature that tries to find out what means can be used to make people litter less in the forest.
But I am looking for studies that try to find out how much garbage is in the forest, how this garbage is distributed and what this garbage is made of (plastic, metal, paper, ...).
Unfortunately, so far I have not found anything about this. I hope that someone here can help me further.

Many thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Indeed. That is correct. But I'm looking for scientific studies that examine littering in an ordinary forest

Comment: I'd argue that there's much different between different countries and forests. Can you narrow it down to a country?

Comment: Of course. I look at Germany in particular. But also international works would be very helpful for me.

Comment: Studies on specific wastes may be available but all types in one study- quite tough.

Comment: Studies on a specific type of waste would already be a great help. Could you name some?

Answer (score 5):

So far, I thought there won't be any studies on the overall scenario of waste disposals. After searching in depth, I have found studies on illegal waste dumping sites in Polish forests. Hope these will be helpful.

Jakiel et al. (2018) assessed the spatiotemporal distribution of wastes in the Ojcow National Park, Poland. Number of dumping sites and volume of different types of wastes were determined through field observation. They categorized the dumping sites into very small, small, medium and large sized. It is a very comprehensive study.

Another study by Zablocki et al. (2011) identified forests and natural depressions as the most common places for illegal waste dumping. Quantitative measurements of waste volumes can be found in this paper. Kolanowski and wisiniewki (2012) found total volume of 50 m<sup>3</sup> garbage in the forest area of Ostrów Mazowiecka community.

**Bibliography**:

1. Jakiel M., Bernatek-Jakiel, A., Gajda, A., Filiks, M. & Pufelska, M.(2018): Spatial and temporal distribution of illegal dumping sites in the nature protected area: the Ojców National Park, Poland, *Journal of Environmental Planning and Management*, DOI: 10.1080/09640568.2017.1412941
2. Kolanowski, B. & Wisiniewski, J. (2012). Assessment of the size and position of wild dumps in the White Forest in the municipality of Ostrow Mazowiecka classified as a
   Natura 2000 [in Polish]. *Infrastruktura i Ekologia Terenów Wiejskich*, 2 (I), 99. Accessed from: https://agro.icm.edu.pl/agro/element/bwmeta1.element.agro-47c8e24c-3441-477d-9abc-261699a5b8b2
3. Zablocki, Z., Podlasinska, J. & Kruczek, I.(2011) Characteristics of illegal waste dumping sites located within area of Kobylanka community [in Polish]. *Folia Pomeranae Universitatis Technologiae Stetinensis, Agricultura, Alimentaria, Piscaria et Zootechnica*. Vol.283 No.17 pp.41-50 https://www.cabdirect.org/globalhealth/abstract/20123068877
4. Antczak, E., 2020. Regional Patterns in Dumping Sitesin Poland - Analysis in Context of the New "Sustainable" Waste Policy. *Polish Journal of Environmental Studies*, 29(2), pp.1037-1049. DOI: 10.15244/pjoes/108484

Comment: Great! Many thanks. This helps me a lot to get started!